# Parse.com PHP new user

Tags: php, forms, parse-platform

I am messing around with the new Parse.com php SDK and like always a little confussed with their docs. They say to add a new user you can use code like this:

```
$user = new ParseUser();
$user->set("username", "my name");
$user->set("password", "my pass");
$user->set("email", "email@example.com");

// other fields can be set just like with ParseObject
$user->set("phone", "415-392-0202");

try {
  $user->signUp();
  // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
} catch (ParseException $ex) {
  // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
  echo "Error: " . $ex->getCode() . " " . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Which I understand whats going on here but that is a hard coded way to set a user. If I want a signup form how do incorperate that into their code? I was thinking of you can just do:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <p><input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email"></p>
    <p><input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
</form>

<? php 
   $email = $_POST['email'];
 ?>
```

the just pass the email for example like `$user->set("email", $email);`. Would that work and be best practice??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some recommendations:

- You should first test if a `POST` request was made before you use `$_POST` variables;
- You should probably do some validation on your input, like checking if it really contains an e-mail address in the e-mail field;
- Personally I would put all the controller stuff (processing the input) at the top and the html output at the end.

So something like:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
  // process / filter input

  // store input
}

if (no_post_or_input_not_valid)
{
  // show form
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense for sure. I guess the real question would be then would using a post variable like that to set up a user be the right way?

Comment: @Packy Yes, using a form and `POST` is a logical and common way to collect and process user input.